# Can I simultaneously apply styles to many DOT nodes taken from multiple subgraphs?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Consider this DOT sample:

```
digraph Foo
{
    subgraph clusterA
    {
        A -> B;
    }

    subgraph clusterB
    {
        X -> Y;
    }

    subgraph connection_type_1
    {
        edge [color=red];
        A -> Y;
    }

    subgraph connection_type_1
    {
        edge [color=green];
        B -> X;
    }

    subgraph node_type_1
    {
        node [style=filled, color=".5,.5,.5"]; // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
        X [label="foo"];
        A;
    }
}
```

The structure is set out in the two clusters and the edges are added later in semantically/cosmetically equivalent groups. The edges are coloured as expected.

But this doesn't work with styling nodes. The marked line has no effect unless I move it into one of the `cluster*` subgraphs, but then it applies to all nodes within that subgraph.

What's odd is that `label=foo` works in the final subgraph, whereas `style` doesn't.

I have a feeling that the answer is going to be "you can only set node attributes the first time you mention them", but is there a way to say "the following nodes, wherever they are, should all have the following attributes"?

Comment: Also, every node should only be part of one subgraph. I'm pretty sure you'll get some warnings with this graph.

Answer (score 4):

the line does not work, as it sets default attributes only and the nodes have been created already. the default attributes have no effect. the label is a concrete attribute overriding any default values and therefore takes effect.

So you should reorder the code to

1. create all nodes (with default attributes)
2. create all edges (again with default attributes)
3. assign the nodes to clusters

steps 2 and 3 would create the nodes with the defauls attributes then active. your example did work for the edges only by accident, as you did try it for non existing edges only. it would not have worked for the 2 already defined edges in the clusters.

```
digraph Foo {
    subgraph node_type_1 {
        node [style=filled, color=".5,.5,.5"];
        A;
        X [label="foo"];
    }
    subgraph node_type_2 {
        node [style=none];
        B;
        Y;
    }
    subgraph connection_type_1 {
        edge [color=red];
        A -> Y;
        A -> B;
    }
    subgraph connection_type_2 {
        edge [color=green];
        B -> X;
        X -> Y;
    }
    subgraph clusterA {
       A;
       B;   
    }
    subgraph clusterB {
        X;
        Y;
    }
}
```